# Measuring Frame Size in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, resolution, frame-rate

I'm a little new with Unity and have been trying to measure how much data (in bytes) is produced by my game in Unity. The goal is to see how small changes in my game would affect the type/amount of data being generated in each frame.

For example, if I have a 40 fps game with 1920x1080 resolution, what would be the size of each frame in bytes?

Any thoughts, advices or alternative ideas are very, very welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: There's two or three kinds of "data" involved here: 1) how much memory is being used by the game in RAM, 2) how much data is sent from the CPU to the GPU in order to render the game 3) the data size of the resulting render. Your question is unclear and seems to be interested in the 3rd choice, which is completely useless information (it will always be 2,073,600 bytes of color information at that resolution).

Comment: If you are interested in determining how changes to your game affect its performance, it would be most immediately helpful for you to learn how to use Unity's [profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html).

Comment: If you want to see performance on frames you can compare 'Time.deltaTime' instead, deltaTime is the time invested on last frame so higher  is slower and less performance and lower is faster and better too.